# How to transfer AWS RDS to different role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have two AWS roles/accounts, and I hosted our PostgreSQL in one account, and later I was notified this role would be disabled shortly, and I need to transfer our database to another AWS accounts. So I made a snapshot of the DB from one to another. I'm wondering if the original account is deleted in the future, does my snapshot also get impacted? Thanks for the clarification[image]

Comment: You seem to be conflating roles and accounts.   Sounds like you created an RDS server in one *account* and now you need to create it in another *account*.  If that's the case, yes, deleting the account will delete all resources in that *account* even if those resources are shared (which is a permissions thing, not an ownership thing).

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/account-transfer-rds/

Comment: I agree @erik258 observation here.  Are you trying to transfer your RDS Database into a new AWS Account or just add a new role with database access, remove the old database permission, and keep the old role?  If clarify this question, I think a solution can be found.

Comment: Hi Albert, Yes, I'm trying to transfer our AWS RDS to another AWS account, and I made a snapshot of the database, looks like if the original AWS account is deleted, the snapshot in the new account will also get wiped out, any other solutions? Thanks!

Comment: you should recreate an RDS instance from the snapshot before removing the old account

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @erik258. I am sharing this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/account-transfer-rds/) that says you can't transfer resources between accounts. However, you can migrate Amazon RDS resources to another account.

To migrate Amazon RDS resources to another account, follow these instructions:

1. Create a DB snapshot.
2. Share the snapshot with the target account.
3. Create a new DB instance in the target account by restoring the DB snapshot.